# What can be the reason for the InvalidQueryException: Unknown identifier?

Tags: java, exception, cassandra, apache-camel, endpoint

I have a table in the Cassandra defined with some columns.
I have Cassandra 2.2.0 and Camel 2.17.1.

```
cassandra@cqlsh> DESCRIBE TABLE logkeyspace.mytable

CREATE TABLE logkeyspace.mytable (
    id text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    col03 text,
    col04 text,
    col05 text,
    col06 text,
    col07 text,
    col08 text,
    col09 text,
    col10 text,
    col11 text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    ...
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX mytable_idx_07 ON logkeyspace.mytable (col07);
CREATE INDEX mytable_idx_09 ON logkeyspace.mytable (col09);
```

Command (with the other order of the columns):

```
cassandra@cqlsh> INSERT INTO logkeyspace.mytable(id,timestamp,col11,col08,col06,col03,col07,col09,col04,col10,col05) VALUES ('1',dateof(now()),'TNT','SOL','FB','CS','RT','ST','H','s','p');
```

Works well.

But the same query fired from camel cassandra end point ended with exception:

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown identifier col09

Only the col09 is not known.

This column was added later by using ALTER TABLE logkeyspace.mytable ADD col09; CQL command.

I had also checked, that when I remove only the col09, then all works fine, so it is not a problem e.g. with the length of the parameters list.

**Where to search the problem, which might be the root cause of this?**

The important part of the stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown identifier col09
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50) 
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37) 
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:79) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.cassandra.CassandraEndpoint.prepareStatement(CassandraEndpoint.java:169) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.cassandra.CassandraEndpoint.prepareStatement(CassandraEndpoint.java:180) 
        at org.apache.camel.component.cassandra.CassandraProducer.doStart(CassandraProducer.java:55) 
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3275) 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doAddService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1243) 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1204) 
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:442) 
        ... 73 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown identifier col09
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:102) 
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:205) 
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:182)
```